# Content Query and Current User AD fields

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part

Is there an easy approach to setup query filters for CQWP to use the current users Department, Location etc fields from their profile.

I know you can get values from the Page Field Filter in the CQWP:
[PageFieldValue: fieldName] , but doesnt look like you can use [CurrentUserValue: field] from the Current User Filter :p

The idea is to filter some Content Types that has a corresponding column for Department. So users only get the items taged with their Department. And one of the criteria is that the solution needs to be close to out of the box.

Comment: What version of SharePoint 2010 are you using? Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: It's for an Enterprise Server PirateEric